# Where is DeleteMediaType() defined?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, include, directshow, platform-sdk

When implementing the example from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd387907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx I have a problem with DeleteMediaType() and VisualStudio 2010: this function is not defined. I found a header Mtype.h should declare it but that does not exist for VS2010. Shouldn't all the headers and libraries be there without installing some additional SDKs?

Where is DeleteMediaType() defined?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows SDK \Samples\multimedia\directshow\baseclasses\mtype.* files. You are normally supposed to include `.h` and link `strmbas?.lib` to make it available to you, but you don't have to: you might prefer to either include this into project directly, or duplicate the function (it's simple and wraps a couple of `CoTaskMemFree` calls).

Comment: But shouldn't that be part of the standard VS2010 installation? dshow.h and strmbas?.lib are there but that mtype.h is not?

Comment: No, it's a part of Windows SDK.